# How to check the status of mail server (SSL, SMTP port 465) in C++

Tags: c++, email, smtp

Ping is not working. Telnet is not an option, sending a mail also. Preferably a function from a library that returns true or false.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by working you mean open, you can just connect to the port and see if the socket opens successfully.

If you mean that it's accepting valid SMTP over SSL, then you'd need a library that connects and issues a trivial SMTP command like HELO or something.

[Chilkat](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/c++_smtp_ssl.asp) has library code and examples for this.

Example connect code for win32:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <wspiapi.h>

void tryconnect(const char * host, const char * port)
{
    SOCKET Socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *resAddrInfo = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *ptr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    int result = 0;

    printf("Connecting to %s:%s\n", host, port);

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    result = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &resAddrInfo);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printError("getaddrinfo failed");
        return;
    }

    ptr = resAddrInfo;
    Socket = WSASocket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printError("Error Creating Socket");
        freeaddrinfo(resAddrInfo);
        return;
    }

    result = WSAConnect(Socket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printError("Error Connecting");
        closesocket(Socket);
        freeaddrinfo(resAddrInfo);
        return;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(resAddrInfo);
    printf("Success!\n\n");
}
```

Comment: When a try connect to the server by ping all I get is a timeout, but the server is working.

Comment: Thanks, but Chilkat is 20 Meg library, a bit of an overkill :)

Comment: If you're just trying to replicate ping, then open a socket to that port and see if it connects.

Comment: John, what headers are you using for this function winsock, ws2tcpip ??

Comment: also, use the Ws2_32.lib library too

Comment: Yes I had to add #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") : )

Comment: The function fails at "getaddrinfo failed". Is it possible that the server is refusing connection without authentication ?

Comment: Hmm; getaddrinfo is just essentially a DNS lookup.  Something else is wrong.

Comment: I checked the error of getaddrinfo and I got 10093 WSANOTINITIALISED
10093. So I added 

WSADATA data;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);

And now Everything is Working ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an SSL connection to the SMTP server and attempt to read a line from the stream. The server should send a greeting message as soon as you establish a connection like "220 smtp.domain.com"

Comment: Don't forget to connect over an SSL link if you do this..:)